# Can the status of erwa change?

Tags: halacha, clothing, tznius-modesty, hair-covering

Can a body part which may reasonably br presumed to have the status of erwa for a particular woman ever lose that status?

Some examples are if a woman is widowed or divorced can she legally uncover her hair? Some rabbis issue heterim for a shiddukh to take place.

If a single woman takes on covering her hair, can she after many years uncover ot again even with hatarath nedarim?

If a woman takes on a full coverage dress code, can she start showing forearms or leg below the calf in public?

How permanent is this status of erwa?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Abigail! Thanks for sharing your question. Perhaps you would be interested in these other [168 question about modesty](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tznius-modesty). Or these [34 questions about hair covering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hair-covering). Hope to see you around.

Comment: What do you mean by "erwah"? The term has different meanings in different contexts. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Why is she switching her practice? Did she move communities to a place where that body part isn't covered? Why then would her previous practice matter? I don't understand what your concern is with these cases. Why would divorce affect the need to cover her hair? What does taking on a certain dress code have to with erwah?

Comment: Doesn't the status of a woman's hair change from not being erva, to being erva after she gets married?